# Adding UITextField to UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

I've looked through countless SO answers on this subject and cannot find what I am looking for.

I have a view I created in a xib file. It has a `UITableView` as a subview. I hooked up the delegate and data delegates to the controller and it works.

Now, I want to load a custom cell in the `UITableView` - the cell needs to have a `UILabel` a `UITextField` and three `UIButtons` that are only visible when a condition is met. My question is simply this:

Can I create a custom cell in a separate xib file with these elements that I need - the load it in the tableview and connect the UI elements to my viewController?

I've tried the above but IB does not allow me to make connections to my view controller.

Can anyone gov me some tips here?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a custom cell and add the required UI elements into it.  It will work. You don't have to make the connection with the view controller, connections you have to make with the UItableViewCell subclass.

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials for google request "create custom uitableviewcell tutorial", just repeat or use source code.

Comment: Try this tutorial:- http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Nice find. Thank you @aToz

Comment: Great! I will add some tutorials as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference,

[Custom TableViewCell tutorial 1](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)

[Custom TableViewCell tutorial 2](http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/how-to-create-simple-tableview-with-custom-cells)