# ios: Textfield duplicates data in uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

Data from textfield duplicates in my tableview cell whenever i scroll the tableview. Textfield repeated for every 6 rows again & again.

How to remove duplicate data from textfield using custom cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *Identifier= @"ProductCell";
    PlaceOrderTableViewCell * ProductCell = [ProductsTblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Identifier];
    if (ProductCell==nil)
    {
        ProductCell = [[PlaceOrderTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:Identifier];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why that happens, is because the `cells`get reused, to improve the speed of your `tableView`. If you would have like over 1000 cells, then it would have to load all of them then display them. When it gets reused, it loads only the ones that have to be displayed.

A workaround for this is to either create an array and do like this:

```
[textField setText:[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

But for more flexibility and time consuming would be to create an `NSDictionary`, and store the appropriate text for the appropriate indexPath. Like this:

```
[textField setText:[my_dict objectForKey:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not duplicate data, you are using `UITableViewCell` incorrectly. For performance reasons cells are reused after they go offscreen, a `UITableViewCell` should only be used to display data from the model and when it gets reused the previous data is replaced by the one from the new data model entity

You should add a bit more information to your question, How are you setting the values of the cells?

**EDIT**

If you need to get the value from an `UITextField` you should implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` specifically [textFieldDidEndEditing:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing:) Also you should take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell) which explains a simple `UITableView` with `UITextField` implementation.

Also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21549050/adding-uitextfield-to-uitableviewcell) as some interesting tutorials you might want to check

Comment: how can i get text for textfield in tableview

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting same data into your textfield , its means that you are getting dequeue cell, u need to change your model class to give textfield data based on index path of the cell, something like this

textfiled.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Note: Don't assign textfield.text value at the time of cell creation, this may be another reason , you r getting same data.